# Displaying local DOCX, DOC, XLS, XLSX file in iframe in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to display locally stored DOCX, DOC, XLS, XLSX files in a view but I am having problem with that. It did work for PDF's but it's not working those above mentioned file types.

Is there any extension or package to be installed? I need help with this please.

**Index**

```
@model IEnumerable<NoteBlocks.Models.NotesInList>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List Notes";
}

<h2>List Notes</h2>

    <p id="buttonsInPTag">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">@Html.ActionLink("  Create Textual Note", "CreateWithtext", new { id = @ViewBag.ListID })</span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">@Html.ActionLink("  Create Note from Document", "CreateWithDoc", new { id = @ViewBag.ListID })</span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">@Html.ActionLink("  Create Image Note", "CreateWithImage", new { id = @ViewBag.ListID })</span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">@Html.ActionLink("  Create Audio / Video Note", "CreateWithMedia", new { id = @ViewBag.ListID })</span></button>
    </p>
    <hr />
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="panel-group col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span id="spanNoteNameHeading">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NoteName): </span>
                    <span id="spanNoteName">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NoteName)</span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (item.TextDescription != null)
                    {
                        <span id="spanTextDescription">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TextDescription)</span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var extn = item.customFile.Split('.').Last();
                        if (extn == "png" || extn == "jpeg" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "gif" || extn == "tiff" || extn == "raw")
                        {
                            @*To image display*@
                            <span id="spanContent">
                                <img src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" id="imgInSpan" />
                            </span>
                        }
                        else if (extn == "mp4" || extn == "mov" || extn == "wvm" || extn == "flv" || extn == "mkv" || extn == "avi")
                        {
                            @*Do video display*@
                            <span id="spanContent">
                                <video controls id="vidInSpan">
                                    <source src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" type="video/mp4">
                                    <source src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" type="video/mov">
                                    <source src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" type="video/wvm">
                                    <source src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" type="video/flv">
                                    <source src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" type="video/mkv">
                                    <source src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" type="video/avi">
                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                </video>
                            </span>
                        }
                        else if (extn == "mp3" || extn == "aac" || extn == "ogg" || extn == "wma" || extn == "wav" || extn == "aiff")
                        {
                            @*Do audio display*@
                            <div id="audioContent">
                                <audio controls id="audInSpan">
                                    <source src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" type="audio/mp3">
                                    <source src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" type="audio/aac">
                                    <source src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" type="audio/ogg">
                                    <source src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" type="audio/wma">
                                    <source src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" type="audio/wav">
                                    <source src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" type="audio/aiff">
                                    Your browser does not support the audio tag.
                                </audio>
                            </div>
                        }
                        else if (extn == "pdf")
                        {
                            @*Do pdf display*@
                <span id="spanContent">
                    <iframe src="@Url.Content(item.customFile)" class="pdfInSpan" id="pdfInSpan" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
                </span>
                        }
                        else if (extn == "doc" || extn == "docx" || extn == "xls" || extn == "xlsx" || extn == "mht")
                        {
                            //Do docs display
                            <span id="spanContent">
                                //filepath
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.customFile)
                                
                                <iframe src="src=@Url.Content(item.customFile)" id="docInSpan" type="application/msword"></iframe>
                            </span>
                        }
                    }
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.NoteId }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.NoteId }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.NoteId })
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    @if (item.CreationDate!=null && item.UpdateDate == null)
                    {
                        <span id="spanCreationDateHeading">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreationDate): </span>
                        <span id="spanCreationDate">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDate)</span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span id="spanCreationDateHeading">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreationDate): </span>
                        <span id="spanCreationDate">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDate)</span>
                        <br />
                        <span id="spanUpdateDateHeading">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UpdateDate): </span>
                        <span id="spanUpdateDate">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdateDate)</span>
                    }
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     }
```

In CSS, I gave width and height to iframe, overflow hidden but that is not the case rn, problem is to display the file on view. below mentioned is the link where I am getting this error instead of file.

> https://imgur.com/a/X1eJzmG

I even tried converting it to MHT file format and it is not working either.

Comment: PDF viewing has been built in to browsers for quite a while and happens without needing any extra extensions. Unfortunately asking for off-site resources is off-topic for [so]

Comment: It is not about PDF viewers. Its about document, and there's a problem in displaying a docx, doc, xls, xlsx file. PDF is displaying fine using iframe but cannot view other documents. As an alternative, if you can suggest a way to convert these files to pdf in controller, that'll also help.

Comment: Yeah sorry. Forgot to say that the situation is not the same for MS Office Word and Excel files and it's a completely different story.